# Can I place fertilizer on planted seeds?

Tags: stardew-valley

I just planted a bunch of crops, but completely forgot to fertilize the tilled ground beforehand. I'm on the same day as the seeds were planted, if I put fertilizer on the planted seeds, does it take effect?

The fertilizer tool tips say to apply it to tilled earth, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

All straight fertilizer, basic and quality, will only apply on bare tilled earth.  You will need to put it on the ground before you put down the seeds.  If you try it afterwards with the seeds on the ground it won't even attempt to use it.

As DanmakuGrazer points out in [the other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/261160/95753), alternate soil buffs like speed-gro and water-retaining will still work at any point (tilled, planted, or even halfway to harvest), so long as there's not any other buff in the soil already.  I am not certain if you would get a full benefit from speed-gro planted mid-cycle, but that seems doubtful.

Comment: Did you actually test in game? Saying that any kind of fertilizer needs to be applied before planting seeds is just straight up wrong.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - honestly, no, as each of the soil buffs are described exactly the same, so I presumed (and since I'm still shipping crops and don't have a vast artisan pipeline like I've seen others do, I never bothered with anything but fertilizer).  Anyone else sees this, please give some upvotes to the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

Having just closed the game, I can safely say that, at least in version 1.06, only Fertilizer needs to be mixed into the soil before planting seeds. Both Retaining Soil and Speed-Gro can be used at any point during a plant's growth.